# looking for efficient way to use redis with node.js

Tags: node.js, redis

I've coded up some examples for a chat room using redis and node.js, but before I continue on this path, I want to know if this is the best way to be doing it:

```
var redis = require('redis')
, cache = redis.createClient(cfg.redis_port, cfg.redis_host)


function getUsers(cb){
    cache.select(cfg.redis_db, function(err, status){
        cache.get('chat.users', function(err, data){
            var users = data && JSON.parse(data) || [];

            c.log('get users', users);
            cb(users);
        });
    });
}

function addUser(user, cb){
    getUsers(function(users){
        users.push(user);

        cache.select(cfg.redis_db, function(err, status){
            cache.set('chat.users', JSON.stringify(users), function(){
                c.log('cache set', arguments);

                c.log('add user', user, users);
                cb(users);
            });
        });
    });
}

function removeUser(user, cb){
    getUsers(function(users){
        users = _.reject(users, function(val){
            return user.nick === val.nick;
        });

        cache.select(cfg.redis_db, function(err, status){
            cache.set('chat.users', JSON.stringify(users), function(){
                c.log('cache set', arguments);

                c.log('remove user', user, users);

                cb(users);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

The reason I ask is it seems rather cumbersome to have to do `cache.select` all over the place then `cache.get`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Redis, once the DB is selected, it remains selected until another `SELECT` is issued. And because the Node Redis client queues commands that are issued before the client is ready, you can do something like this:

```
var redis = require('redis')
, cache = redis.createClient(cfg.redis_port, cfg.redis_host);

cache.select(cfg.redis_db);

// the rest of your code
```

It doesn’t look very Node-ish, but it works and is shown (as a comment; easy to miss) in one of the examples on the [node-redis home page](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis).